# In Php, Calling an array when it's name is stored in a variable

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible duplicate:**
>   [Convert a String to Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433302/php-convert-a-string-to-variable)

for example:

$test = array("this","is","a","test");

$what_array_to_read = "$test[0]";

function to read the array $test[0]

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433302/php-convert-a-string-to-variable On a personal note, if you need to do this, IMHO you're doing something wrong. What's the use case for this?

Comment: maybe you want to stuff your arrays into a hash.

Answer (score 4):

That is only possible using `eval` which should be avoided.

But if you do

```
$what_array_to_read = "test";
$what_index_to_read = 0;
```

then you can access

```
$$what_array_to_read[$what_index_to_read]; // will echo "this"
```