# Get value from multiple dimension associative array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have a POST request array that looks like this

```
 $request = array (size=2)
      'licence' => string 'uDyQwFwqV7aQG2z' (length=15)
       'user' => 
         array (size=7)
           'first_name' => string 'Danut' (length=5)
           'last_name' => string 'Florian' (length=7)
           'username' => string 'daniesy9' (length=8)
           'password' => string '123456' (length=6)
           'rpassword' => string '123456' (length=6)
           'email' => string 'daniesy+1@me.com' (length=16)
           'phone' => string '9903131' (length=7)
```

This in fact is an array which represents values sent by a form. I know the name of the elements, for example the username input has the name of `user[username]` and i have to find the related value from the array, by name. Something like:

```
$key = "user[username]";
$request[key];
```

Any idea how to do this?

*I know that the correct way to do it is `$request["user"]["username"]` but it's quite complicated because i have to use the fields names from the form which are `user[username], user[firstname], etc` and it might have up to 4 levels of depth.*

Comment: you could probably restructure the form so you had known keys to use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433302/convert-a-string-to-variable

Comment: @Dagon that is not an option...

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments but similar Question to 
[Convert a String to Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433302/convert-a-string-to-variable)

<strike>eval('$username = $request["user"]["username"];');</strike>

**Edit**

Eval not a valid suggestion as request data.

So I would suggest the second method on this post

```
<?php
$request = array(
    'user' => array(
        'username' => 'joe_blogs'
    )
);

function extract_data($string) {
    global $request;

    $found_matches = preg_match_all('/\[\"([a-z]+)\"\]/', $string, $matches);
    if (!$found_matches) {
            return null;
    }

    $current_data = $request;
    foreach ($matches[1] as $name) {
            if (key_exists($name, $current_data)) {
                    $current_data = $current_data[$name];
            } else {
                    return null;
            }
    }

    return $current_data;
} 

$username = extract_data('request["user"]["username"]');
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that i only have strings like these `user[username]` with which i should extract values from the array. Also, being a form requested data, isn't eval kind of dangerous?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry didn't think about that

Comment: Ive updated it do you want me to update it for just user[username]?

Comment: No no, it's ok! Thanks. I think I have a solution too

Comment: Sorry but i find my answer better

Comment: Sorry I thought you used mine! No worries

Answer (score 0):

```
function findInDepth($keys, $array){
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if(!isset($array[$key])){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if(is_array($array[$key])){
        return findInDepth($keys, $array[$key]);
    }
    return $array[$key];
}
$key = "user[username]";
$keys = preg_split("/(\[|\])/", $key);
echo findInDepth($keys, $request);
```

This function solves my problem. It first splits the string (aka the input name) into an array of keys and then recessively searches in depth the array by keys until it finds a value which is not an array and returns `FALSE` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate keys with dots. Primitive example:

```
<?php

class ArrayDot
{
  protected $array = [];
  public function __construct(array $array) {$this->array = $array;}

  public function get($path)
  {
    $array = $this->array;
    foreach(explode('.', $path) as $key)  {
      $array = $array[$key];
    }
    return $array;
  }
}

$array = [
  'user' => [
    'username' => 'tootski',
  ]
];

$a = new ArrayDot($array);

echo $a->get('user.username'); # tootski
```