# PHP: Can we get reach DYNAMICALLY any key we want to in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamically-generated

Can we get reach DYNAMICALLY any key we want to in multidimensional array?

```
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Mantovarka']=3;
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Castrool']=91;
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Separator']=10;
$f['Kitchen']['Product']=18;
$f['Kitchen']['Textile']=19;
$f['Kitchen']['Blue things']['Juicemaker']=25;
$f['Kitchen']['Blue things']['Freegener']=13;
$f['Kitchen1']['Blue things One']['Microwave']=4;
$f['Kitchen1']['Blue things One']['Iron']=24;
$f['Kitchen1']['Dishes One']['Separator']=110;
```

For example, if I want to reach 'Kitchen1' and 'Dishes' and 'Iron', respectively.

```
 var_dump($f['Kitchen1']);
 Output:
 [
    'Blue things One' => [
        'Microwave' => 4
        'Iron' => 24
    ]
    'Dishes One' => [
    'Separator' => 110
    ]
 ]

 var_dump($f['Kitchen']['Dishes']);
 Output:
 [
    'Mantovarka' => 3
    'Castrool' => 91
    'Separator' => 10
 ]

 var_dump($f['Kitchen1']['Blue things']['Iron']);
 Output:
 24
```

I tried to reach it as:

```
 $kitchenKeys = "{'Kithcen1'}"; 
 var_dump($f[$kitchenKeys]);
 Output:
 NULL

 $dishKeys = "{'Kitchen'}][{'Dishes'}";
 var_dump($f[$dishKeys]);
 Output:
 NULL

 $ironKeys = "{'Kitchen1'}][{'Blue things One'}][{'Iron'}";
 var_dump($f[$ironKeys]);
 Output:
 NULL
```

Can we assign keys to $kitchenKeys or/and $dishKeys or/and $ironKeys dynamically, to get any key`s value in multidimensional array?

Comment: I think you might need `eval()` to do that

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by dynamically. You can easily assign a value to a variable to access it. e.g. `$value1="Kitchen1"; $value2 = "Dishes One"; print_r($f[$value1][$value2]);`

Answer (score 1):

*Chay22 is correct and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433302/convert-a-string-to-variable)*

this will work; `eval('var_dump($f['.$dishKeys.']);');`

you can also make it as a usable variable like this

```
eval('$newkey = ($f['.$dishKeys.']);');
var_dump($newkey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a function to access the inner keys using dot notation. For example "key1.key2.key3". An example of such can be found here: https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-helpers/blob/master/src/helpers.php

But the eval method described above will work as well. However you are more prone to errors due to unset keys, and if you're setting the dynamic key from user input, sanitization becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I'd do it, dynamically, is to get an Array of the values, and then, inside a foreach (inside a function if you'll use it more than once, I did for the sake of display) generate a string for the elements of the array. Then set a string that contains the command you want to run, and finally execute it with `eval()`. Be careful with what these arrays are going to contain, especially if it's user-generated, as `eval()` can be dangerous.

```
$dishKeysArray = array("Kitchen", "Dishes");

$evalString = getEvalString($dishKeysArray);

eval($evalString);

function getEvalString($array){
    $elementString = "";
    foreach($array as $arr){
        $elementString .= "['$arr']";
    }
    $evalString = 'var_dump($f' . $elementString . ');';
    return $evalString;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Note the specific use of double & single quotes, as sometimes we want to actually use the value of an array and sometimes we want to literally output the array name (`$f`)

Comment: thanks for suggestion!
I used like this:

`$my_array = array("0" => "Kitchen1","1" => "Blue things One");
extract($my_array,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,'index');`


`$dishKeys = "'{$index_0}']['{$index_1}'";
eval('$newkey = ($f['.$dishKeys.']);');
var_dump($newkey);`